# Lagged predictors in irregular-time / asynchronous / time-unconstrained data

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lags, unevenly-spaced-time-series, growth-model

In growth curve modeling or other approaches, when time is *constrained/synchronous/regular* (i.e. panel/wave data; all observations occur synchronously), lagged prediction is trivial - simply add t-1 as a predictor. This is all very easy in the SEM framework for growth curve modeling.

However, if data is irregular/time-unconstrained (observations are temporally asynchronous), a multilevel/hierarchical approach is necessary. Its not clear to me, then, how lagged prediction could be accomplished - descriptions I've seen range from very-difficult to literally impossible.

Are there any approaches that might be workable? Is it just necessary to ~snap~ time-unconstrained data to waves/fixed observations and use SEM approach? A simple example that accomplishes lagged prediction in time-unconstrained data would be incredibly helpful

Thank you

Comment: I have not heard the terms *constrained/unconstrained* used in such a context. *Regularly/irregularly or evenly/unevenly spaced time series* may be a more standard expression. But perhaps I am just ignorant of the terminology of SEM?

Comment: I've read all three with "irregular" being used more frequently in the economics literature - they are equal, thank you

Comment: I've seen it help to treat lag as a moderator of time's effect: https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2012.715557

Comment: Excellent source, and such a simple solution. including the "lag" estimator looks almost identical to the formulation used by STATA in their example using "menl" package, which has a term "[ time_i_j - time_(i-1)_j ] ", for i = 1...nj observations of j=1...J individuals.